# Problems in maths competition vs problems in advanced cs degree and programming

Tags: secondary-education, mathematics

I have some experience in the initial stages of maths olympiads. So , a curiosity arises whether the problem solving methods and the difficulty of the methods given in any advanced computer science degrees and programming in professional world harder than the problems in international mathematical Olympiad?

Comment: @njuffa I donot know anything about industrial problems but out curiosity asking that are there any problems in industry which are lot harder and creative than maths Olympiad problems?

Comment: IMHO, they *cannot be compared* this way in a meaningful fashion because they are very different kind of tasks.

Comment: Problems, methods and difficulty in professional programming, advanced CS degrees and math olympiads are about as related as apples, broccoli and sauerkraut.

Comment: Knuth has [written](https://www.cs.ou.edu/~diochnos/about/KnuthCSMaths.pdf) about this